# Selenium select all table elements using powershell webdriver

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, selenium-chromedriver

PowerShell Selenium, I need to get select all list of elements in the table, I have tried below code but no output

```
$listElements = $ChromeDriver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@id='object4']//table//tr//td/img")
$actions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions($ChromeDriver)
$actions.KeyDown("Keys.LeftControl")          
foreach ($element in $listElements) {
    $element.Click()
}
$actions.build().perform()
$actions.keyUp("keys.LeftControl")
```

With this still i am not able to control the keydown to select the elements

[Even I have tried through SendKeys("Keys.LeftControl") but not selecting all at once, can anyone please help in this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLJLh.png)

```
> $listElements = $ChromeDriver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@id='object4']//table//tr//td/img")
> $actions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions($ChromeDriver)
> $actions.SendKeys("Keys.LeftControl")     
> foreach ($element in $listElements) {
    $actions.Click()
}
> $actions.build().perform()
> $actions.SendKeys("keys.LeftControl")
```

The Console output is like

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
```

The issue is only a single element selecting, but not all elements are not selected

Comment: You need to highlight them in the browser? For what reason? Seems likely to be an XY problem

Comment: @DougMaurer Yes, I need to Select all elements in a table, To move all elements from left table to right table by using inset selection button. When I trying to select, only single element getting selected, but not able to select all elements using keydown(''Keys.LeftControl"), Can you please suggest a way to fix this?